# Check if an object is defined in html

Tags: html, object, null, undefined

In HTML, I have an object tag as follows:

```
<OBJECT ID="objectid" CLASSID="some-class-id" CODEBASE="some-codebase">
```

I have written a function in JavaScript to access this object.

I checked the null value as follows:

```
if(objectid==null){-----}
```

i want to check if the object is undefined or is empty. Do we have any functions to check so?

Comment: Please make the question more clear....

Comment: Did you mean to check if the <object> tag is in the DOM or if the <object> is supported by a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

To check if a variable contains a value and exists, use:

`if (variable) {}`

For example, to check that you have obtained the `objectid` DOM element:

`if (document.getElementById("objectid")) {}`